# Add an image in Beamer' s "outline" slide?

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

Say,

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>
    \frametitle{Outline for section \thesection}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
}


\begin{document}

\section{Test section one}
\begin{frame} Test \end{frame}
\begin{frame} Test \end{frame}
\section{Test section two}
\begin{frame} Test \end{frame}
\begin{frame} Test \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

How is it possible to add an image in the outline section? In particular, I want to be able to choose the position of the image. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outline slide is just a frame like any other of your frames. You can add an image to its definition in your preamble.

Changing the position works the same as changing the position of images on all your other slides.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>
    \frametitle{Outline for section \thesection}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck} % <- image added here
  \end{frame}
}


\begin{document}

\section{Test section one}
\begin{frame} Test \end{frame}
\begin{frame} Test \end{frame}
\section{Test section two}
\begin{frame} Test \end{frame}
\begin{frame} Test \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]